# Как расшифровывается микропроцессор 8086 и i386?

Tags: ассемблер

8086 это просто название микропроцессора или есть конкретная расшифровка?

И как расшифровывается i386? Как я понял intel 3 поколения 8086 (опять же, хочу знать его расшифровку)?

Comment: [ссылка на википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/8086)

Answer (score 1):

8086 - это сокращенное название микропроцессора [Intel 8086](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/8086). Первый 16-битный микропроцессор компании Intel. Именно от этого процессора берёт своё начало известная на сегодня архитектура [x86](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86).

i386 - это сокращенное название микропроцессора [Intel 80386](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/80386). Первый 32-битный процессор с архитектурой [x86](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) третьего поколения фирмы Intel.